# how to create a custom ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want a ViewPager with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter that instead of using one fragment use a pair of fragments for viewpager, for example:  A1 A2 ; B1 B2 ; C1 C2 ; D1 D2  ....
when activity starts viewpager use first fragment to display and when user click on that fragment(or a button) first fragment is replaced with second fragment an if again click second fragment is replaced by first fragment in fact by clicking viewpager pages switch between fragments.
i have no idea how to create such a thing, i need your help , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, got it now. To implement flash cards would not be that difficult and it only requires a regular viewpager. The most of the work will have to go into creating the fragment that the viewpager will hold. In this fragment is where all card flipping animation code (along with the final presentation of the other side of the card, is where that should take place.

You can start by looking into view animations (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html). You may possibly need to use drawable animations(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) to make the card flipping effect look really authentic.

Comment: i do not think this is possible

Comment: It is possible to host two viewpagers in a single layout. Viewpagers act just like any other andorid widget except that they are from the support package (and that won't affect how it is rendered on a layout). Try it by putting both viewpagers in a linear layout and then setting the layout_weight for each viewpager to half of the sum_weight of the linear layout. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: no, you did not understand my problem, i want create a flashcard app that need to show just one fragment in viewpager and when user clicks, other fragment loads with Card Flip Animations, got it?   and if u know better way to create flashcard app let me know ....thanks